# SignalR unable to receive broadcast when in Microsoft Edge

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, microsoft-edge, signalr.client

We have problem getting message from Hub when we're in Microsoft Edge.

The connection is established, sending message from Client -> Server works as expected, but we're not receiving any response from server push. The same code works in Chrome & Firefox though.

Below is some code that we're using:

JS:

```
$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function () {
        $.connection.myHub.server.broadcastMessage().done(function (data) {
            console.log("broadcastMessage result: " + data); //work as expected when client request data from server, server does return the data
        });
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log("Connection failed!");
    });

$.connection.myHub.client.showMessage = function (msg) {
    alert(msg); //not working, in Microsoft Edge we're not receiving anything, this function is not triggered at all
};
```

C#:

```
public string BroadcastMessage() {
    Clients.All.showMessage("ABC");
    return "Hello World";
}
```

We're not completely unable to receive any broadcast 100% of the time though, however it does happens 95% of the time.

Although we're not able to receive any broadcast from server, but subsequent request from Client -> Server works as expected.

`public override Task OnConnected()` are not hit when we're in Edge too, but the code block does hit when we're in Chrome / Firefox.

Any idea? Is this a problem with SignalR or Edge?

P/S: We're using JQUERY 3.3.1 & SignalR 2.3.0

**UPDATE 1:**

We tried to remove everything and made a empty project to see if it's a problem with SignalR. Apparently if it's a completely new project, SignalR doesn't have this problem, but after I implemented Form Authentication, the problem starts to happen, I'm guessing is it because sometime when server trying to broadcast message to client, it's not authenticated or the cookies are not set?

Below is the code we used to implement our Forms Authentication:

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity identity)
                {
                    FormsIdentity id = identity;
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;

                    string userData = ticket.UserData;
                    string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                    HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Web.Config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="LoginCookie" loginUrl="/Account/Login" protection="None" path="/" defaultUrl="/Account/Login" timeout="3600" />
</authentication>
```

Code in Web.Config to block folder access

```
    <location path="CMS/Admin" allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
   </location>
```

The sample page were placed inside /CMS/Admin.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your c# code in:

```
public string BroadcastMessage() {
   IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<myHub>();
   context.Clients.All.showMessage("ABC");
   return "Hello World";
}
```

Without `IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<myHub>();` i don't able to work with signalR

Comment: Why this should work if he has a problem in the browser? In the firefix it is running so he has the right hubcontext in his c# server part..

Comment: i'm sorry for the bad suggestion, i will remain in listen for a good answer